# How to replace strings from a list and replace them with integers?

Tags: python-3.x

The list is to be replaced by names, but for now we need to use ID numbers that use zeros in the beginning. This is the issue in our code currently, seems we need a string integer correspondence that just isn't working out, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
list = ['01001000', '01100101', '01111001']

for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == '01001000'
    list[i] = '800000842'
print(list)
```

Comment: what about `list[i] = 800000842`? that way you would have a list with integers? also as recommendation, list comprehension and dictionary seems better here. Using variable name `list` pollutes namespace as you cant use `list()` function anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace str values to integers use this:

```
# Note: don't use reserved words to variable name in python
# reserved words :  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Reserved-Keywords-in-Python
mylist = ['01001000', '01100101', '01111001']
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = int(mylist[i]) # this makes the change
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Whenever I convert a binary string to an integer I have trouble working with any binary value bytes that begin with "0". Any idea on how to swiftly convert a message: "Hey" from text to binary UTF-8 and then from there to a specific data sheet that corresponds that im pulling from excel?? If not thats okay I appreciate this help right here!!